# Are there pin differences on the audio jack between a 2015 and a 2017 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a pair of these headphones:

[image: Soundmagic PL30]

They work fine for audio **input** and output on my Android phone (LG G5) and my 2015 MacBook Pro (tested with Quicktime recorder).

But when I plug them in to my 2017 MacBook Pro and record audio the sound is barely detectable, even when turned all the way up (on input and output). They are fine for audio output though.

Did Apple change something between the two MacBook Pro models? Is it more likely that my MacBook Pro has a defective connector?

Here are the audio settings on my 2017 MacBook Pro:

[image: audio settings 2017 MBP]

Answer (score 2):

Answering instead of deleting question:

I took this to the company help desk and they determined that my macbook 2017 probably has a defective ground on the headphone jack.